# How to transfer the existing class to the next order div and add a new class?

Tags: jquery

I have a question.
I created a page with the following structure.

```
<div class="cover-header">
  <span class="box-header checked">test1</span>
  <span class="box-header">test2</span>
  <span class="box-header">test3</span>
  <span class="box-header">test4</span>
  <span class="box-header">test5</span>
  <span class="box-header">test6</span>
  <span class="box-header">test7</span>
</div>
```

When I scroll through the page, a class named 'red' will be added to the box that had the 'checked' class, and I want the class named 'checked' to move on to the next box. (It will be deleted from the existing box)
It's going to change like the code below.

```
<div class="cover-header">
  <span class="box-header red">test1</span>
  <span class="box-header checked">test2</span>
  <span class="box-header">test3</span>
  <span class="box-header">test4</span>
  <span class="box-header">test5</span>
  <span class="box-header">test6</span>
  <span class="box-header">test7</span>
</div>
```

I tried 'next()' and 'after()', but it didn't apply.
If I only use next(), the class will be added to all div...
I want to be added only to the next div. So, used 'closest()' together, but it didn't apply.

```
$('.box-header.checked').next().closest().addClass('checked');
```

This should continue until the last div. As a result, if you scroll to the end, it will look like the code below.

```
<div class="cover-header">
  <span class="box-header red">test1</span>
  <span class="box-header red">test2</span>
  <span class="box-header red">test3</span>
  <span class="box-header red">test4</span>
  <span class="box-header red">test5</span>
  <span class="box-header red">test6</span>
  <span class="box-header checked">test7</span>
</div>
```

Comment: don't be shy... show us how you tried to achieve the goal!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] **showing your attempt** and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `after` certainly wouldn't be relevant here. `next` would, but not `after`.

Comment: *"When I scroll through the page, a class named 'red' will be added to the box that had the 'checked' class..."* By what? By your code? Is that the code you want to change? Or is it done by some other code? If so, when/how do you trigger the change to `checked`?

Comment: Re your edit: The call to [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) doesn't make any sense. If you remove it, your code should work.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It's a little complicated to explain. About 10 boxes of the same height are stacked vertically, and a box named "menu" is fixed on the floor. When I scroll through the screen, there is a moment when the top position values of each vertically stacked box match the box height value named 'menu'. -> \ 'checked' class movement.

Comment: @dayoungjung - The layout on the page ("fixed", "stacked", etc.) is irrelevant. It's where the elements are in relation to each other in the DOM. If your DOM is as shown, your code would work without `closest`. If your DOM **isn't** as shown, how could we possibly help you with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code will fulfill your problem

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.cover-header').scroll(function(){
        $('.cover-header>span').each(function(){ 
            var x =  $(this).position();
            if(x.top < 10){ 
                console.log(x.top);
                $('.box-header').removeClass('red').removeClass('checked'); 
                $(this).addClass('red').next().addClass('checked');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```